# Querying 2 tables using INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to join two tables on a INSERT... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE statement. I am trying to dynamically printing out data from 2 tables. I have echo out data from one successfully into form fields. Half way through the process i have realised i also need data from another table.

So i was wondering in the following statement:

```
$example_query = "INSERT INTO example(x,y) VALUES 
            (?,?)
         ON DUPLICATE KEY 
         UPDATE
         x = ?
         ,y = ?";
```

If i could also call another table, or what is the best practice for this.

Comment: What would calling another table help you out with while inserting data?

Comment: @N.B i need data from that table, to show data about the product

Comment: So how is an insert helping you **retrieve** data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create two separate inserts, not one complicated. Then run both inserts in transaction to be sure both are executed.

`BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO table1 ...
INSERT INTO table2 ...
COMMIT`

Comment: Thank you. much appreciated